# PHP: Evaluating variable in string, and then changing value of variable

Tags: php

I have a string such as the following:

```
$s1 = "Apples";
$s2 = "$s1 are great";
echo $s2;
```

My understanding of PHP is that the double-quotes in the second line will cause $s1 to be evaluated within the string, and the output will be

```
Apples are great
```

However, what if I wanted to keep $s2 as a "template" where I change $s1's value and then re-evaluate it to get a new string?  Is something like this possible?  For example:

```
$s1 = "Apples";
$s2 = "$s1 are great";
echo $s2 . "\n";

$s1 = "Bananas";
$s3 = "$s2";
echo $s3 . "\n";
```

I find that the output for the following is:

```
Apples are great 
Apples are great
```

What I am hoping to get is more like:

```
Apples are great 
Bananas are great
```

Is such a thing possible with PHP where I can keep the "template" string the same, change the input variables, and then reevaluate to a new string?  Or is this not possible with PHP?

Comment: Not sure if you would find this satisfactory, but you could use `sprintf("%s are great", "Apples");`

Comment: using a function is advisable.

Comment: The same question for JavaScript: [If a variable is defined in terms of another, can it reflect changes in the binding of the other?](/q/42637782/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do something like this: (just a quick mashup).

```
$template = "{key} are great";
$s1 = "Apples";
$s2 = "Bananas";

echo str_replace('{key}',$s1,$template) . "\n";
echo str_replace('{key}',$s2,$template) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [anonymous function (closure)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for similar result:
(only above PHP 5.3!)

```
$s1 = function($a) { 
    return $a . ' are great';
};

echo $s1('Apples');
echo $s1('Bananas');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reference passing (though it is much more commonly used in functions when you want the original modified):

```
<?php

$s4 = " are great";
$s1 = "Apples";
$s2 = &$s1;

echo $s2.$s4;

$s1 = "Bananas";
$s3 = $s2;
echo $s3.$s4;

?>
```

Output:

```
Apples are great
Bananas are great
```